# Add whatsapp Link with pre defined text messages that include page title and page url

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, whatsapp

i need to insert whatsapp link just like [https://wa.me/[phone](https://wa.me/%5Bphone) number]
but with pre defined text message that are able to insert page title and also page url,
like for example when customer came from

page title: abcd

page url: wesbite.com/abc

the message should include both page title and page url like,

---

hello customer, may i help you

abc

website.com/abc

---

and if customer comes from

page title: efgh

page url: wesbite.com/efgh

the message should be like

---

hello customer, may i help you

efgh

website.com/efgh

---

i am using bigcommerce, and their support doesn't support for themes customization.
and i am also not an IT expert.

this link suppose to show both on header and footer.
is this possible to just add to a theme?

i found a code online like this

const msg = encodeURIComponent("Hello, thanks for contacting us! -- URL: " + window.location.href);
document.querySelector('.whatsapp-link').href = 'https://wa.me/6281381534824?text=' + msg

but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: If you have WhatsApp links both in your header and footer, and if both links have a `.whatsapp-link`, you would need to change them both. You code won't do that, it would only change the header link. It also wouldn't get the page title, only the URL. Regarding on how to use the code - you need to edit the part of your site that is included on all of the pages, and it would have to be somewhere at the very bottom of the page (so it would activate once all of your elements have loaded - I'm assuming there are no dynamically added elements) .